# JSON File getting output as a dictionary for every row and need to create a DataFrame from it

Tags: python, json, numpy, pandas

I have a .json file and when I convert it into a Data frame by -

```
df = pd.read_json('tummy.json')
```

The output looks like -

```
     results
0   {u'objectId': u'06Dig7sXhU', u'SpecialProperti...'
1   {u'objectId': u'07VO1j4gVC', u'SpecialProperti...'
```

Every row seems to be a dictionary itself. I want to extract every row and create a Data Frame out of it. I would really appreciate some help on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(( {u'objectId': u'06Dig7sXhU', u'SpecialProperties': u'456456'}, 
               {u'objectId': u'07VO1j4gVC', u'SpecialProperties': u'878421'}))
df = pd.DataFrame({'results':s})
print df
                                             results
0  {u'objectId': u'06Dig7sXhU', u'SpecialProperti...
1  {u'objectId': u'07VO1j4gVC', u'SpecialProperti...

print pd.DataFrame([x for x in df['results']], index=df.index)
  SpecialProperties    objectId
0            456456  06Dig7sXhU
1            878421  07VO1j4gVC
```

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! Maybe you can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accept mark. Thanks. But it is up to you.